# Fourier transform: how did my book derive this?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'm not sure I understand how to calculate Fourier transforms. How do I deal with the $i$ in the following?

Let $$f(x) = e^{ cx} - e^{(c+1)x}, \ \ c > 0$$

for $x < 0$ (and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise).

My book states the Fourier transform $\hat{f}(\xi)$ is

$$ \hat{f}(\xi) = -\frac{1}{(\xi - ic)(\xi - i(c+1))}$$

and I have no idea how it computes this?

How do you calculate $$ \int_{-\infty}^0 f(x) e^{i\xi x}dx$$

and get the same answer as above?

Comment: Should the $a+1$ be $c+1$ instead?

Comment: Yes, it should. Edited.

Comment: Could you show how you get the latest integral? There is certainly an error of variable substitution or other.

Comment: The transform itself is from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, but since $f(x) = 0$ for $x > 0$, they only take limits from $-\infty$ to $0$.

Comment: I calculated the integral in Maple and the book's solution seems to be correct?

Comment: What is the convention that your book is using for the Fourier transform?